# Turn by Turn Navigation for Google Map on Laptop

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

How can I generate voice navigation for turn-by-turn directions for Google Maps on my laptop?

Comment: not possible currently > https://support.google.com/maps/thread/9133402?hl=en

Comment: Is your laptop connected to a GPS or you just want to test the App on Windows?

Comment: I'm not using a app just the URL version.

Answer (score 0):

As Mapperz mentioned, it is not available. However, an option would be to use [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com) Android Emulator. (We are using windows 10 Home Edition).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I do not have a BT GPS to test it out with Bluestacks if you want to do the turn by turn live, however you can see the directions if you want to.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would this return voice turn by turn navigation?

Comment: I know that the start location is correct. There is a voice, but I am not sure how it will behave on the road. This is of course provided that you can connect a GPS to it.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Store probably has some apps you could use instead of installing Android Bluestacks.

We offer a WPF Windows Desktop app that offers Turn by Turn Directions (offline disconnected optionally available if you load data) http://mapdiscovery.techmaven.net